# -MT vs -MD options in Visual Studio compiler

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015

Good afternoon,

I want to understand these options a little better, 
This is the reading I have done so far:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx

Up to this point I understand that I need to compile all the libraries involved in the project with the same /MT, /MTd, /MD, /MDd options

From the article above, it seems the /MT and /MTd options statically link the visual C library, msvcrt.lib to the executable, whereas the /MD option requires you to have this DLL.

The DLL usually ships with Visual C++ redistributable (if compiling for release) or visual studio (if compiling a debug release) ? Correct?

So if the client does not have the correct version of redistributable installed or the correct version of visual studio, they will need to install these if I build with /MD or /MDd options respectively,

If I use /MT and /MTd, the client should not need to do this

Is this correct?
Would /MT option be the recommended choice for applications that are meant to be distributed and used across variety of windows OS's

Thanks for you input.

Comment: If you are only building a single executable then `MT` make your life easy.  If you are building a program that comprises an exe and supporting dlls then `MD` will be required unless you invest a lot of time and effort into dynamic memory management.  If you build `MD` then include the appropriate Microsoft runtime redistributable package with your installer and run it during the installation process.

Comment: Unless your user has Visual Studio (and the correct version) installed, the /Mxd versions of your library will be totally useless to them. The only ones that can be used are the /MT and /MD versions. Also, the client can't just install debug libraries -- they actually need an installation of Visual Studio

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Only the /MDd version needs Visual Studio itself installed. The /MD version needs the Visual C++ Redistributable installed and that can be bundled with the application, possibly just by including the DLL depending on the version of Visual Studio.

Comment: I would have thought that the `/MTd` would also need Visual Studio to be installed, since it is a debug library.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Since `/MT` and `/MTd` link the run-time library directly into the executable or DLL, forming a single unit, they don't require anything to be installed.  The result is a completely self-contained binary.